# VBA Active X button to take user to first cell of updated row

Tags: vba, excel, activex

I have a spread sheet which has a button that transfers all the entered data into another sheet. I have then made a second button that takes you to this log should you want to view it, however it takes you too the last cell filled. The log has a lot of columns so i want to make the 'go to log' button to take you to the first cell in the last row that was filled.
all i have at the moment is a simple formula to take you there.

```
    Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Log").Activate

    End Sub
```

Comment: Try to add `Columns(1).Show`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are sure that your code is taking you to last Cell filled, and you are expecting the control to go to the first cell of the row then below piece will do.

```
Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 1).Select
```

Comment: Maybe not the last filled cell but the last cell selected, it always takes me to the end of the row whether it has data in it or not. But that's working so thanks!